# Alternative to e-mail collection of data

Tags: tools

*Situation*

I am currently working in a company that is not technically advanced and my skills in project management are very limited.

*Problem*

For weekly, monthly and quarterly reporting there are a number of KPIs that I can retrieve from data lake. However, there are a number of KPIs that are needed to be collected manually, since there are database/program where such information can be retrieved.

As a result, I every week, month or quarter I need to manually send out e-mails to all relevant parties to collect data, often chasing, since people do not read messages.

*Question*

As a result, I was wondering people with experience here have alternatives to suggest.

Ideally, it would be a solution where answers are stored for a long time, since I need to be able to demonstrate auditors/regulators what has been filled in and when.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for tool recommendations, that's off-topic for PMSE. It may or may not be on-topic at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. If it's a process question, you need to provide more detail on what data you're looking for, how you plan to *use* it, and why your organization isn't collectively able to agree on a solution. Otherwise, this is simply an opinion poll where every answer is potentially correct, and that's also off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on your company. As you say, it's not technically advanced, and as such solutions that depend on technical changes may be somewhat hard to implement.

#### Stable storage format

I would start in your own area and devise a scheme in which you organize the collected data. As a software developer, I'm always inclined to develop an automatic solution, but you're probably better off with a manual process that you follow reliably. This may be as simple as having Excel files organized in folders by reporting period. The key is that you don't change the format and process too often, so you get familiar with it, and maintaining the data becomes fluent over time.

#### Automated collection

For the data that currently needs to be collected using e-mail, I would try to meet with the people who have access to that data to find ways of automatically extracting it. If it's in databases, something like a scheduled script to perform some SQL and send you the results might be enough. Setting up the first of such scripts will likely be a bit of work and will require the assistance of knowledgeable colleagues. The work will become easier once you have done it for one or two data sources, as you then know whom to ask and how to best format the data.

#### More automation - maybe, maybe not

You might be tempted to add more automation so that data collected from the different sources is automatically consolidated. I would not plan for that until you have sufficient experience with manually performing the process, so you really know what works and should be automated. However, you should also consider that part of data collection is quality control, and it might be better to keep the manual consolidation step as you are able to see data inconsistencies early. Putting such checks into code is possible but harder than you might think, and probably not worth it, depending on the volume of data.